# grep with regex - filter lines containing consecutive same number and ignoring whitespace

Tags: regex, bash, grep

a file.txt containing several lines of strings

```
abc
abc1
abc11 11abc
abc111
abc abc1
```

i know how to filter lines containing 3 or more consecutive same single digit number

```
grep -E '([0-9])\1{2,}' file.txt
>> abc111
```

how to modify the regex so that it will ignore whitespace and produce below output?

```
abc111
abc11 11abc
```

Comment: what is your definition of "number" ? Do you mean "digit" ?

Comment: `grep -E '([0-9]).*\1.*\1'` ?

Comment: yes, a single digit number

Comment: "3 or more consecutive same number" is a slightly ambiguous requirement. Eg, `111111` has "3 or more `1`s" and "3 or more `11`s". Please see if you can put some conditions or ambiguity resolution rules.

Comment: i have edited the question to "3 or more consecutive same single digit number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match optional whitespace chars in between:

```
([0-9])[[:space:]]*\1[[:space:]]*\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vXCTag/1)